# Qt application doesn't print ěčř

Tags: c++, qt, encoding

this application doesn’t print first three letters.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
        QString a = QString::fromUtf8("ěčř1šžýáíé");
    QLabel win(a);
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Also, is your source code actually encoded in UTF8?

Comment: Sry, dont say some import things, like i use Ubuntu 13.10 or i have Qt Creator 2.7.1 Based on Qt 5.0.2 (64 bit). I see that you compile it on Windows so it is some Linux problem.

Comment: yes i contol it in Edit->Select encoding.

Comment: As the original post, I got the sample problem too. I use Qt creator 3.0.1 with Qt 4.8.5 (MSVC2010 32bit) plus Windows 7 as the runtime environment.

Comment: Source code must be in UTF8 and compiler must know about that. And all problems must be gone.

Comment: @DeadWarlock could you post you version of Qt creator and windows ?

Comment: Windows7 Qt 5.2.0 MInGW 4.8

Answer (score 0):

This is why I prefer avoid in code use c-strings which are charters coding depended.
First try like this:

```
QString a = QString::fromWCharArray(L"ěčř1šžýáíé");
```

---

the  only explanation why this didn't work is that compiler is using encoding different then your editor. Assuming the you applied other advices your editors encoding is UTF-8 and compiler has something else.

According to [this article](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt) you should try change system wide encoding to utf-8 or check compiler settings.

You can try add in pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -finput-charset=utf-8 -fexec-charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
// Utf-8 (hex) for each characters in "ěčř1šžýáíé"
const char s[] = { 0xC4, 0x9B, 0xC4, 0x8D, 0xC5, 0x99, 0x31, 0xC5, 0xA1,
                   0xC3, 0xBD, 0xC3, 0xA1, 0xC3, 0xAD, 0xC3, 0xA9, 0x00 };
QString a = QString::fromUtf8(s);
QLabel win(a);
win.show();
```

Comment: @Daffy, it it doesn't work, what do you see instead? Please copy and paste the content of the label.

Comment: @Daffy, hm, that looks like you see only the half of the text. Maybe your label is too small? Or overlapped with something else?

Comment: Are you read comments to my  question ? Because Tay2510 have same problem and have different version of Qt creator, Qt and have windows. But DeadWarlock don’t have problem. [And picture of application is there.](http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=snmekoqmq.png)

Comment: Added: I've compiled and run the code on another machine and it worked fine. In sum, [not working build]:Win7 32bit/Qt 4.8.5/Qt creator 3.0.1/seperate installation/MSVC2010build. [working build]:Win7 64bit/Qt 5.2.1/Qt creator 3.0.1/integrated online installation/MSVC2010build.  FYR

Answer (score 0):

Store your source file in UTF8 encoding (without BOM). Your programming editor should allow to do so.